# Button background Color disappears if clicked outside of the button/on body

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have created a tabpane using html,css,and javascript so the issue I am facing is that when I click outside the button the background color of the the active tab's button disappears .I am able to change the color of the buttons while switching between the tabs by using onfocus() and onblur() functions ,but whenever I click outside the button/on body active tab's button's background color disappears.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

```js
// console.log('hii');

function fun1(a){
    // console.log(a);
 var x = document.getElementById(a)  
 var data = document.getElementsByClassName('inner_section')
 console.log(data);
 for(var i=0;i < data.length;i++){
    data[i].style.display="none"
}
    x.className +=" slide-in-bottom"
    x.style.display = "block";

}

function fun2(b){
  b.style.backgroundColor="#ff6136"
  var d = document.getElementById('button_1')
  d.classList.remove('active_button')
}

function fun3(c){
    c.style.backgroundColor="white"
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.section h3,h1{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
.section h3{
    color: gray;    
}
.main_button_class{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}
.active_button{
    background-color: #ff6136;
}
.main_button_class button{
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    padding-left:2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(61, 61, 61,0.3);
}
.icons{
    width: 20px;
    height: auto;
}
.divs{
    margin: 1.5em;    
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: -7px 8px 7px lightgrey;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.divs:hover{
    background-color: #ff6136;
}
.inner_divs_1{
    display: flex;
}
.inner_divs_1 h4{
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
.inner_divs_2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 11px;
    font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
}
.text-muted{
    color: gray;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;

}
.abc{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.pqr{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.xyz{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#dish_2{
    display: none;
}
#dish_3{
    display: none;
}
.inner_images{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 1em;
}

.slide-in-bottom {
    -webkit-animation: slide-in-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
            animation: slide-in-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes slide-in-bottom {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px);
              transform: translateY(1000px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
              transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes slide-in-bottom {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px);
              transform: translateY(1000px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
              transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 7 part 2</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index2.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d98e4752db.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="section">
        <h3>our menu</h3>
        <h1>Restaurant & Bar</h1>
        <div class="main_button_class">
        <button id="button_1" class="active_button" onclick="fun1('dish_1')" onfocus="fun2(this)" onblur="fun3(this)" ><img src="tray.png"class="icons"/> Main</button>
        <button id="button_2" onclick="fun1('dish_2')"onfocus="fun2(this)"onblur="fun3(this)"><img src="beer.png"class="icons"/> Dessert</button>
        <button id="button_3" onclick="fun1('dish_3')"onfocus="fun2(this)"onblur="fun3(this)"><img src="cheers.png"class="icons"/> Drinks</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Part 1 -->
    <div class="inner_section"id="dish_1">
        <div class="abc">
        <div class="inner_section1" >
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
            <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-3.jpg.pagespeed.ic._eupGZGDhZ.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
            <h4>Grilled Beef with potatoes<br>
               <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
            </h4>

        </div>
        <div class="inner_divs_2">
            $29
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="divs" >
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.QNS0cGseKC.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Fruit Vanilla Ice Cream<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
        
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">  
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-5.jpg.pagespeed.ic.h2NHjzs2rt.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Asian Hoisin Pork<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
    
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-6.jpg.pagespeed.ic.LHa9ujD1jc.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Spicy Fried Rice & Bacon<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-7.jpg.pagespeed.ic.QKJ9esJPYg.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Mango Chili Chutney<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inner_section2">  
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-8.jpg.pagespeed.ic.X1UarM12S1.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Savory Watercress Chinese Pancakes<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-9.jpg.pagespeed.ic.RMbgqdIacd.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Soup With Vegetables And Meat<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- -->
            <div class="divs">
                 <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src=" https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-10.jpg.pagespeed.ic.AjEzQKSqtq.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Udon Noodles With Vegetables<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src=" https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-11.jpg.pagespeed.ic.SSID_aLKfC.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Baked Lobster With A Garnish<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdish-8.jpg.pagespeed.ic.X1UarM12S1.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Octopus with Vegetables<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Part 2 -->
    <div class="inner_section"id="dish_2">
        <div class="pqr">
        <div class="inner_section1" >
  
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.SW4Gb-2Sdd.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Grilled Beef with potatoes<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs" >
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-2.jpg.pagespeed.ic.PXl-DGXsd5.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Grilled Beef with potatoes<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-3.jpg.pagespeed.ic.QA267i3edb.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Grilled Beef with potatoes<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.ExoXl1Yy0j.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Grilled Beef with potatoes<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-5.jpg.pagespeed.ic.yC-EI1C2Sl.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Grilled Beef with potatoes<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inner_section2">  
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-6.jpg.pagespeed.ic.xuS6fI649R.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Tiramisu<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-7.jpg.pagespeed.ic.uGV1uE0TVM.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Chocolate Cream<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-8.jpg.pagespeed.ic.nzJWrF6g2R.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Pizza Pie<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-9.jpg.pagespeed.ic.b75RlkqLs7.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Sicilian Ricotta<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divs">
                <div class="inner_divs_1">
                    <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdessert-10.jpg.pagespeed.ic.q2XtdIPwdq.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                    <h4>Mango FLoat<br>
                       <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="inner_divs_2">
                    $29
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<!-- Part 3 -->
<div class="inner_section"id="dish_3">
    <div class="xyz">

    <div class="inner_section1" >
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.RCrXYE6lI1.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Lemon Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
     
        <div class="divs" >
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src=" https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-2.jpg.pagespeed.ic.SpvM1G0DSa.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Guava Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="  https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-3.jpg.pagespeed.ic.gVXfnHFXF_.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Guava Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.3viOU5YJzH.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Cola<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -->
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-5.jpg.pagespeed.ic.ZiCZ5rrjr4.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Wine<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_section2">  
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-6.jpg.pagespeed.ic.u6RPJcbH6h.webp " alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Beer<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-7.jpg.pagespeed.ic.FxQPy3duGU.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Mango Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-8.jpg.pagespeed.ic.E5AmxrGlDY.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Apple Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-10.jpg.pagespeed.ic.0RAnNKt8zC.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Orange Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divs">
            <div class="inner_divs_1">
                <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/cozy/images/xdrink-9.jpg.pagespeed.ic.qnCVD_wbaQ.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="inner_images">
                <h4>Strawberry Juice<br>
                   <span class="text-muted">Meat, Potatoes, Rice, Tomatoe</span> 
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_divs_2">
                $29
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index2.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"focus" in the browser is a construct generally used for input boxes so the website can know where you're currently typing something, and/or for sight impaired so they can use tab navigation. It is not meant for events that change the state of the site and leads to unexpected behavior when misused. I recommend you don't use that for a menu selector setup like you have

Instead of using this mechanic to keep track of which menu is selected, you can use the functions you already created to set a "selected" class on the button and remove that same class from all the other buttons.

You can get all the buttons by setting a class on all of them in html. then you can get the list of buttons in javascript like so:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("menu-buttons");
```

Which returns an array. You can remove the "selected" class from an element like so:

```js
el.classList.remove("selected");
```

Then add the selected class to the element that was clicked like so:

```js
el.classList.add("selected");
```

By the way, I do not recommend using the onclick html attribute, but rather use javascript to [set event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Then you also get access to the `Event` object which you can use to get the clicked button more conveniently. Here's an example:

```js
function selectMenuHandler(event) {
  for (var el of document.selectElementsByClassName("menu-selected")) {
    el.classList.remove("menu-selected")
  }
  event.target.classList.add("menu-selected")
}

for (var el of document.selectElementsByClassName("menu-button")) {
  el.addEventListener("click", selectMenuHandler);
}
```